# Tabs not resizing properly for sortables

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-ui-sortable

I have the following script:

http://jsfiddle.net/oshirowanen/mYx5y/3/

Why is the height of the tab which contains the sortable elements not resizing it's height properly to contain all the sortable elements?

Comment: @experimentX, I have further clarified the question for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column element within the tabs are floated and needs a clear after so the tabs div is the right height.

A quick fix would just be to use clearfix. use the following css:

```
.clearfix:after { content: "."; display: block; height: 0; clear: both; visibility: hidden; }

.clearfix { display: inline-block; }

* html .clearfix { height: 1%; } /* Hides from IE-mac \*/

.clearfix { display: block; }
```

and give the div with id="tabs" a class="clearfix"